# Is it possible to hide peers' IP from each other when forcing TURN/RELAY?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

If so do you know which services/projects have functionality like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TURN is only for media and it hides the peer address by default.
However the address is being transmitted via SIP signaling (including SDP), so you should remove it from there and not on the TURN server.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, I need to intercept the sdp info coming from the signaling instance before it arrives to the client ?
Also do you know any libraries that I could easily implement something like this?
Atm I am playing with licode but I dont know if am heading the right direction

Comment: This can be done on the server what you are using for the signaling relay (be it NodeJs or a SIP server).